# docker insecure registry, http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to push my local docker images to docker registry that runs on another machine on my local network. it's working fine when I try to push from registry host machine. But I'm unable to push it from my computer. And I've added insecure-registries parameter to **/etc/docker/daemon.json** file on host machine properly but still nothing.

**docker info on docker registry host machine**

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 6
  Running: 6
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 6
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 0197261a30bf81f1ee8e6a4dd2dea0ef95d67ccb
 runc version: v1.1.3-0-g6724737
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-99-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.935GiB
 Name: mongo-dav-ubuntu
 ID: KAQO:FLF5:CNCJ:M6GN:W6ML:LBGW:YJ5S:IPM4:FJLF:FH5G:BIXU:HBUR
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  {host-machine-local-domain}:9000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

**error I'm getting on my computer**

```
The push refers to repository [{host-machine-local-domain-name}:9000/alpine]
Get "https://{host-machine-local-domain-name}:9000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

**docker ps output**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS          PORTS                                             NAMES
4a55c18e4141   registry:2                  "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   About an hour ago   Up 25 seconds   5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->80/tcp, :::9000->80/tcp   vibrant_shockley
```

note that I've set HTTP_SERVER_ADDR to 80

Comment: Looks like there is a http/https clash between the client and server.

Comment: can you explain more?